# Bash: expand a list of coordinates (sed?)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a list of simple coordinates (longitude, latitude pairs) like

```
110 30
-120 0
130 -30
0 30
```

and try to expand it to this:

```
110 30 110\272E 30\272N 110 30 LON0
-120 0 120\272W 0\272 -120 0 LON0
130 -30 130\272E 30\272S 130 -30 LON0
0 30 0\272 30\272N 0 30 LON0
```

**Examining the first line:**

`110 30 110\272E 30\272N 110 30 LON0`

`110 30` The first two values just stay the same

`110\272E` the third value is basically the first value with an added (octal `\272`) degree symbol and an `E` for positive values or a `W` for negative values

`30\272N` similar to the third value, this is the latitude with an added degree symbol and a `N` for positive and a `S` for negative values.

`110 30` is just a repetition of the first two values

`LON0` is a fixed string for later replacement.

**Things tried so far:**

I played around with `sed`, but was unable to achieve anything remotely useful. I wasn't able to manipulate the matched values depending on them being negative or positive.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

All the best,
Chris

EDIT: @jaypal suggested to add different possible cases that can occur. Original was only one case with minor deviations in value.

EDIT2: Had to adjust the example data due to me not updating all values in the sample data. My apologies.

Comment: So you basically want to duplicate and add `\272E`, `\272N` and `LON0` to each line?

Comment: Basically yes, however the `E` and `N` depend on the value being positive or negative. First value being positive: `E`; negative: `W`. Second value being positive: `N`; negative: `S`. That's my main problem.

Comment: Are you limited to bash/sed, or is a general-purpose language like perl acceptable for the solution?

Comment: bash et al are fine, perl/python/etc would be great but not allowed. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use `awk`? It will be very easy:

```
$ cat file
110 30
-120 0
130 -30
0 30
```

```
awk '
function abs(x) {
     x = x > 0 ? x : x * -1
     return x
}
{
    print abs($1),abs($2), ($1>0?abs($1)"\272E":$1==0?$1"\272":abs($1)"\272W"), ($2>0?abs($2)"\272N":$2==0?$2"\272":abs($2)"\272S"), abs($1), abs($2), "LON0"
}' file
110 30 110ºE 30ºN 110 30 LON0
120 0 120ºW 0º 120 0 LON0
130 30 130ºE 30ºS 130 30 LON0
0 30 0º 30ºN 0 30 LON0
```

If you want to print `\272` instead of `º` just add another backslash to prevent it from interpolating. So modify the above script and use `\\272` where ever you see `\272`.

We print the fields as you desire in your output and the following two syntax:

```
($1>0?$1"\272E":$1"\272W")
($2>0?$2"\272N":$2"\272S")
```

are ternary operators that checks for the positivity of the values. If first is positive use `E` else `W`. If second is positive use `N` else use `S`.

---

#### Update:

```
awk '
function abs(x) {
     x = x > 0 ? x : x * -1
     return x
}
{
    print $1,$2,($1>0?$1"\\272E":$1==0?$1"\\272":abs($1)"\\272W"),($2>0?$2"\\272N":$2==0?$2"\\272":abs($2)"\\272S"),$1,$2, "LON0"
}' file
110 30 110\272E 30\272N 110 30 LON0
-120 0 120\272W 0\272 -120 0 LON0
130 -30 130\272E 30\272S 130 -30 LON0
0 30 0\272 30\272N 0 30 LON0
```

Comment: Yes, I can use `awk` – it seems like I tried the wrong program. My bad. I found a problem while thinking about your solution. In case of latitude == 0° or longitude == 0° there should not be a `E` respective `N`. Just `0\272`. Do you see a way to achieve this?

Comment: @Chris Can you please update your question with different possible data set and expected output. I will update the answer based on that.

Comment: I did as requested. Now all cases should be covered. Thank you for your input!

Comment: @Chris Updated the solution. Your desired output in the question was not entirely in sync. Hope the answer works out for you.

Comment: I was too fast in updating the example data. I missed a lot of the fixed values. My apologies.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you for your help. I did escape the backslash and now have a perfectly working solution.

Comment: Thats great, I did make an update based on your expected output. If you run in to any issues feel free to leave a comment.